# Could not find io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin:1.3.3

Tags: java, android, ormlite, objectbox, android-orm

I am trying to integrate object box in my existing android project but getting error.
Is there any JAVA 8 version issue or object box compatibility issue.
is there any gradle version and object box compatibility issue. i am stuck at this point.

```html
Error:Could not find io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/io/objectbox/objectbox-gradle-plugin/1.3.3/objectbox-gradle-plugin-1.3.3.pom
    file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/io/objectbox/objectbox-gradle-plugin/1.3.3/objectbox-gradle-plugin-1.3.3.jar
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/objectbox/objectbox-gradle-plugin/1.3.3/objectbox-gradle-plugin-1.3.3.pom
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/objectbox/objectbox-gradle-plugin/1.3.3/objectbox-gradle-plugin-1.3.3.jar
```

following are my gradle files
Build.gradle :

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 25
    minSDKVersion = 18
    targetSDKVersion = 25
    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.2"
    supportLibVersion = "25.3.1"
    playServicesVersion = "11.0.2"
    digitsVersion = "1.10.3"
    crashlyticsVersion = "2.8.0"
    facebookStethoVersion = "1.5.0"
    facebookSDKVersion = "4.7.0"
    jUnitVersion = "4.12"
    squareUpOkHttpVersion = "3.9.1"
    squareUpRetrofitVersion = "2.3.0"
    squareUpPicassoVersion = "2.5.2"
    eventBusVersion = "3.1.1"
    commonsIOVersion = "2.5"
    commonsLangVersion = "3.7"
    ThinDownloadManagerVersion = "1.3.0"
    exoplayerVersion = "r1.5.8"
    constraintLayoutVersion = "1.0.2"
    leakCanaryVersion = "1.5.1"
    textDrawableVersion = '1.0.1'
    badgeViewVersion = '1.1.0'
    zxingVersion = '3.5.0'
    multidexVersion = '1.0.2'
    androidTagViewVersion = '1.1.4'
    ical4jVersion = '2.0.5'
    calendarViewVersion = '1.0.4'
    commonsCodecVersion = '1.10'
    concurrentUtilVersion = '3.1'
    AndroidAudioRecorderVersion = '0.3.0'
    objectboxVersion = '1.3.3'
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://objectbox.net/beta-repo/" }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
//        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
//        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.3"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        maven { url "http://objectbox.net/beta-repo/" }
    }
}


dependencies {
}
```

and Module Level gradle :

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath "io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin:$objectboxVersion"
    }
}
configurations {
    // referenced in some portable lib. use android internal instead
    compile.exclude group: 'commons-logging'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'
//apply plugin: 'sonar'
//apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"

   
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    google()
}


android {


    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
//        jackOptions {
//            enabled true
//        }
        android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        applicationId "com.example.example2"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSDKVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSDKVersion
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
//    compileOptions {
//        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
//        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
//    }
    

    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']
        }
        

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


dependencies {


    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile("com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:${rootProject.ext.crashlyticsVersion}@aar") {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile("com.digits.sdk.android:digits:${rootProject.ext.digitsVersion}@aar") {
        transitive = true
    }


    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${rootProject.ext.playServicesVersion}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${rootProject.ext.playServicesVersion}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:${rootProject.ext.playServicesVersion}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${rootProject.ext.playServicesVersion}"

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"

    compile "com.facebook.stetho:stetho:${rootProject.ext.facebookStethoVersion}"
    compile "com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:${rootProject.ext.facebookStethoVersion}"
    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:${rootProject.ext.facebookSDKVersion}"

    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:${rootProject.ext.squareUpOkHttpVersion}"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${rootProject.ext.squareUpOkHttpVersion}"
    compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:${rootProject.ext.squareUpPicassoVersion}"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${rootProject.ext.squareUpRetrofitVersion}"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${rootProject.ext.squareUpRetrofitVersion}"

    testCompile "junit:junit:${rootProject.ext.jUnitVersion}"

    compile "commons-io:commons-io:${rootProject.ext.commonsIOVersion}"
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:${rootProject.ext.commonsLangVersion}"


    compile "com.mani:ThinDownloadManager:${rootProject.ext.ThinDownloadManagerVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:${rootProject.ext.exoplayerVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:${rootProject.ext.constraintLayoutVersion}"

    debugCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:${rootProject.ext.leakCanaryVersion}"
    releaseCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:${rootProject.ext.leakCanaryVersion}"
    testCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:${rootProject.ext.leakCanaryVersion}"
    compile "org.greenrobot:eventbus:${rootProject.ext.eventBusVersion}"
    compile "com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:${rootProject.ext.textDrawableVersion}"
    compile "q.rorbin:badgeview:${rootProject.ext.badgeViewVersion}"
    compile "com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:${rootProject.ext.zxingVersion}"
    compile "co.lujun:androidtagview:${rootProject.ext.androidTagViewVersion}"
    compile "org.mnode.ical4j:ical4j:${rootProject.ext.ical4jVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:multidex:${rootProject.ext.multidexVersion}"
    compile "backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:${rootProject.ext.concurrentUtilVersion}"
    compile "commons-codec:commons-codec:${rootProject.ext.commonsCodecVersion}"
    compile "com.github.tibolte:agendacalendarview:${rootProject.ext.calendarViewVersion}"
    compile "com.github.adrielcafe:AndroidAudioRecorder:${rootProject.ext.AndroidAudioRecorderVersion}"
    debugCompile "io.objectbox:objectbox-android-objectbrowser:$objectboxVersion"
    releaseCompile "io.objectbox:objectbox-android:$objectboxVersion"

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your module's `gradle.build` you are lacking the repo.

Move this part from the top gradle file to the module one:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://objectbox.net/beta-repo/" }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this solution but not working, gives same error.

Comment: In the log, "Searched in the following locations" does not show http://objectbox.net/beta-repo/ but it should...